# Dart define a typedef for simple method which Analyzer return Method invocation or property access on a 'dynamic' target

Tags: flutter, dart

In dart i defined this variable:

```dart
dropDownAddList.addAll(
  [
    {'name': 'Import config from QRcode', 'action': scanQrCode},
    {'name': 'Import config from Clipboard', 'action': importFromClipboard},
  ],
);
```

and when i try to use `action` like with this code:

```dart
onTap: () {
  dropDownAddList[index]['action']();
},
```

`Analyzer` throw this message:

```
Method invocation or property access on a 'dynamic' target.
```

methods:

```dart
Future<void> scanQrCode()async{
    ///
}

Future<void> importFromClipboard()async{
    ///
}
```

now my question is how can i define a `typedef` to solve this issue? can i use `typedef` for that?

Comment: It's not clear what's in scanQrCode, but if it's a function, and not a string, that inner map can only be of type Map<String,dynamic>, and you'll need to cast any value extracted from it as a function to invoke it.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz i updated post with their methods

Comment: Yeah, so you cannot have a Map with String keys, and both Strings and Functions as values.  The only type that encompasses that is dynamic (or Object, but that's not where this typically goes).  So, back to requiring casting, which can be done either with "is" (to take an alternate path if it's not a function) or "as" (which will blow up if it's not a match).

Comment: You *could* define an object with a String and a Future<void> Function() property, and have a list of those, perhaps keyed by the name in a Map.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz could you take me a sample?

Comment: use records instead of such maps: `(String, Future<void> Function ())`, more here: https://dart.dev/language/records - it says: "Records are an anonymous, immutable, aggregate type. Like other collection types, they let you bundle multiple objects into a single object. Unlike other collection types, records are fixed-sized, heterogeneous, and typed."

Comment: something like: `Future<void> fun1() async => print('fun1');
Future<void> fun2() async => print('fun2');
final list = <(String, Future<void> Function())>[
('fun1 dsc', fun1),
('fun2 dsc', fun2),
];
list[0].$2();`

Comment: @pskink i get this error: `The element type '(String, Future<void>)' can't be assigned to the list type '(String, Future<void> Function())'`